# Magento unable to add webp images to category thubmnail

Tags: magento2, image, image-upload, optimization

I want to add webp images to category thumbnail, how can we do this, it gives below error on adding webp images **"File validation failed."**

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 4):

I almost feel it is spammy, but just to mention: A free way of implementing WebP is here: https://www.yireo.com/software/magento-extensions/webp2

Answer (score 2):

Magento does not support webp images.
Use online converter to convert webp image to jpeg then upload it on magento.
https://ezgif.com/webp-to-jpg

In order to optimize your website images, use google page speed, it will convert your images to webp on runtime.

Comment: i know that i am unable to upload webp image to category thumnail it show image not supported

Comment: That's what I am saying, magento do not support webp images, you need to convert it to jpeg then upload it on category thumbnail

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into an image CDN?

Using a CDN like [ImageEngine](https://imageengine.io) will automatically convert your images to WebP for supported devices.  It will even resize your images to the end users device screen size and apply varying rates of compression based on the devices DPI.

Here's a handy guide on implementing it in Magento: https://www.scientiamobile.com/4-steps-to-adding-image-compression-to-magento/

This is a great option because you don't have to manually change your existing images.

Answer (score 1):

You can have .webp for product images in Magento with our [WebP Optimized Images Extension](https://www.jajuma.de/en/jajuma-develop/extensions/webp-optimized-images-extension-for-magento-2).

With this extension there is no need for manually converting or uploading the .webp files.

Conversion is done automatically, with configurable compression supporting different conversion tools and on your own server with no need to use and pay any 3rd Party Service.
This while being 100% compatible with Varnish / FPC as well as any Browser.

Comment: Worth noting that there is another extension that does the same thing but is free: https://github.com/yireo/Yireo_Webp2

Answer (score -1):

In order to serve your image in WebP in Magento, there are ways to this:

- Using Third-Party Services Image CDN like mentioned by @Joseph LoPresti, there are some third party Image CDN like Pico as well. or many other services out there.
- Use extension for WebP, but in order to make this extension to work, you might need a minimum VPS hosted Magento. Such as Amasty, they required certain tools in your Server Operating System (OS), like below :

[image: Warning About WebP Tool requirement]

[See the full guide here](https://amasty.com/docs/doku.php?id=magento_2:google_page_speed_optimizer)

To be able to use [mod_pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module) that are suggested by @Shoaib Munir or (maybe) @Jajuma suggested, you need also need VPS and you may check the compatibility with your host.

- You can manually upload your images to WebP, online converter tool like mentioned by @Shoaib Munir, but the other way around JPG/PNG -> WebP: https://ezgif.com/jpg-to-webp and reupload them through File Manager (CPanel) or FTP (GUI Admin may reject your file) and check the code that load the image (you may want to change the .jpg into .webp, same as the result of your manual conversion process).